# What is 野菜ソムリエ?

Tags: words, food

I have trouble understanding the concept of 野菜ソムリエ.

I have searched [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A8#.E3.81.9D.E3.81.AE.E4.BB.96.E3.81.AE.E3.82.BD.E3.83.A0.E3.83.AA.E3.82.A8) and [others](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E9%87%8E%E8%8F%9C%E3%82%BD%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A8) but I can't understand if it is the name of a media job, or the name of a restaurant job.

I feel it might be more of a cultural question actually, but I don't know yet as I don't understand the word itself.

Comment: I do not know, but have you searched some webpages containing phrases “vegetable sommelier”?

Comment: Your link leads to another link to a page more specific to it: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%26%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC What do you mean by "a media job"? Probably that is not the case.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this seems more about the question of "what is a sommelier" than anything specific about Japanese.

Comment: I asked a Japanese friend, she said it is a skill that some talents learn to run shows on TV or radio. fefe's link also talks about 有名芸能人 in the first paragraph. Apparently they made the term popular. But indeed it is not intrinsically linked to entertainment. Accepting fefe's answer, it seems to be indeed a qualification in the field of nutrition, kind of "certified fruits/vegetables nutritionist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a search on the web, I found [ja.wikipdia.org/wiki/...](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ja/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB&%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC)(also mentioned by sawa) , http://gfhis.com/towa.html , http://www.vege-fru.com/ , etc. From these pages, we can see the "野菜ソムリエ" is not a job, but a qualification. It is a qualification for people withe various knowledge of vegetables and fruits: classification, nutrition, cooking method, quality, etc.